# Task continue with not working upon exception

Tags: c#, task

I am in a strange situation, I am using task and continue with upon faulted i am calling one method to process upon faulted or success but the function does not get fired.

Below is my code but upon expcetion it does not executes the UdpateResult method, what I am missing here.

```
 var task = new Task.Factory.StartNew(SomeMethod());

task.ContinueWith(
 t1 => Handler.UpdateResult(t1.Result, t1.Exception),
 TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);

 try   
 {
         task.Wait();  
 }   
 catch (AggregateException exception)   
 {
   foreach (var innerException in exception.Flatten().InnerExceptions)
   {
      if (innerException is InvalidOperationException)
      {
            throw innerException;
      }

      throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Empty, innerException);
    }   
}
```

Comment: "and continue with upon faulted" - where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to use `t1.Result` within your continuation. If `t1` has faulted, then accessing `t1.Result` will itself throw an exception.

You either need a single continuation which can handle *any* kind of end result, or you should attach different continuations for success and failure cases.

Comment: so I have continue with task instance only? what do you mean by single continuation?

Comment: With 2 different continue with I have sorted it, thanks. But just as an curiosity, why it behaves as? we can already access t1.result and t1.exception we can figure out based on the result state.?

Comment: @KeshavdasM: I'm not sure what you mean by the first sentence of your comment... but you currently *have* a single continuation which will always be called (you're just calling ContinueWith once) and that continuation will fail if the original task fails. *Either* make that continuation handle faulted tasks as well, *or* call ContinueWith twice, once for faulted tasks and once for successful tasks. (There are options you can specify for that.)

Comment: @KeshavdasM: Well what would you expect `t1.Result` to return if the task had faulted? You could use `t1.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion ? t1.Result : SomeDefaultValue` if you wanted.